# R susbet matching "ANY" (union)

Tags: r, subset

I'm attempting to subset from mtcars, such that the rows have a specific column which matches ANY of several values, stored in a list.

```
cylChoices = c(4,6)
subset(mtcars,cyl==cylChoices[1] | cyl== cylChoices[2])
```

However, I'd like to do when cylChoices is of arbitrary length.

I've gotten close to this with for loops, but this results in what feels like unnecessarily long code, for example:

```
cars = list()
cylChoices = c(4,6)
count = 1
for(tempChoice in cylChoices){
count =count+1
cars[[count]] = subset(mtcars,cyl==tempChoice)
}
```

This doesn't produce the same result, but it's getting closer.

Is there any way to match a subset easily?

Thank you very much for your time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use the `%in%` operator to subset the data as requested in the OP.

```
cylChoices = c(4,6)
subset(mtcars,cyl %in% cylChoices)
```

...and the first few rows of output:

```
                mpg cyl  disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb
Mazda RX4      21.0   6 160.0 110 3.90 2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4
Mazda RX4 Wag  21.0   6 160.0 110 3.90 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4
Datsun 710     22.8   4 108.0  93 3.85 2.320 18.61  1  1    4    1
Hornet 4 Drive 21.4   6 258.0 110 3.08 3.215 19.44  1  0    3    1
Valiant        18.1   6 225.0 105 2.76 3.460 20.22  1  0    3    1
Merc 240D      24.4   4 146.7  62 3.69 3.190 20.00  1  0    4    2
Merc 230       22.8   4 140.8  95 3.92 3.150 22.90  1  0    4    2
Merc 280       19.2   6 167.6 123 3.92 3.440 18.30  1  0    4    4
Merc 280C      17.8   6 167.6 123 3.92 3.440 18.90  1  0    4    4
```

`%in% can also be used with the extract operator, such as:

```
mtcars[mtcars$cyl %in% cylChoices,]
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help! 
Your solution works perfectly, I really appreciate your help.

Comment: @rgf98 - thanks, if the answer worked for you, please accept it.

Answer (score 0):

An option with `filter`

```
library(dplyr)
mtcars %>%
     filter(cyl %in% cylChoices)
```